# Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value when object mapper read value

Tags: spring, post, response, objectmapper

When I call restTemplate.postForEntity to my rest api like that:

```
public HashMap<Boolean, Object> find(DriverFindRequestModel findDriverForm) {
    HashMap<Boolean, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(findDriverForm);
    try {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity =
                restTemplate.postForEntity(URL_DRIVERS + "/form", entity, String.class);
        result.put(true, objectMapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), DriverDTO.class));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result.put(false, helperService.getMessageFromError(ex.getMessage()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am getting `Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 172572] (through reference chain: com.example.responses.DriverDTO["tickets"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.responses.TicketDTO["driver"]-> ...`

PostForEntity works correctly, my rest api response the same DriverDTO as in my other application.

DriverDTO has model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DriverDTO {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private List<TicketDTO> tickets;
}
```

tickets is colection of TicketDTO like:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TicketDTO {
    private LocalDate date;
    private Set<OffenceDTO> offences;
    private DriverDTO driver;
}
```

but I do not know where is the problem. In other request everything works. The error message goes on line when I call objectMapper.readValue... and want to cast it to DTO.